# obtaining a date from this string

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I need to obtain a Date object from this String:This is a example)

```
M-27\nJUN-2012  DayOfWeek-dd\nMONTH-yyyy
```

Its impossible? I dont know how to use simpledateformat for this..The \n is a line jump.

Comment: give us example of date representation in String

Comment: whats the length on `DayOfWeek`?

Comment: So the format varies and is encoded in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following SimpleDateFormat:

```
String dateS = "M-27\nJUN-2012";  // your date string
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd\nMMM-yyyy"); // formatter
Date date = fmt.parse(dateS.substring(2));
System.out.println(date);
```

You can really drop out the day of week, because day, month and year defines this day.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) doesn't seem to do days of the week as single letters.  I would take a substring that removes that letter and the dash with it:

```
27\nJUN-2012
```

Then I would use `dd\nMMM-yyyy` as the string you use in the constructor of the SimpleDateFormat.

This should do exactly what you want.  Since you have the day of the month as a number, the day of the week doesn't matter that much to you to create the date object.  If you really want to know the day of the week, then see here: [How to determine day of week by passing specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270272/how-to-determine-day-of-week-by-passing-specific-date)