# Get Current Day (Monday, Tuesday, etc) in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a program that asks the user which day they would like to see a lunch menu for. They can enter any day by name (Monday, Tuesday, etc.). This works well, but I would also like them to be able to enter "Today" and then have the program get the current date and then check the menu for that value.

How would I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270272/how-to-determine-day-of-week-by-passing-specific-date

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Answer (score 12):

This is the exact answer of the question,

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = calendar.getTime();
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date.getTime()));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date.getTime()));
```

Result (for today):

Sat

Saturday

Answer (score 10):

As of Java 8 and its new [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package:

```
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.from(LocalDate.now());
```

or

```
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek();
```

Answer (score 7):

Java 8 :

```
LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().name()
```

Comment: one liner is better