# How to get numeric day in week? Android

Tags: android, simpledateformat

How do you get the numeric day of the week? For instance, Sunday is day 1 in the Gregorian calendar. Using SimpleDateFormat, `d` gets the day in month. Any solution for the numeric day of week?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270272/how-to-determine-day-of-week-by-passing-specific-date

Comment: completely missed this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be "F" : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
new SimpleDateFormat("F").format(new Date());
```