# Getting the day of the week from user input

Tags: java, calendar, dayofweek, monthcalendar

```
Date date= (new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day)).getTime();
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
String dow=f.format(date);

System.out.print("This date is a "+dow);
```

I have the user input a month(1-12) a day(1-31) and a year(1600-2400)
It works fine only it displays the wrong day. For example it says that Jan 1st 2014 is a Saturday but it was a Wednesday.
It is probably because I didn't factor in leap years but I don't have a clue to go about doing that. Neither do I know how to tell it how many days in each month. An array?
Hopefully minimal lines as well.

Thanks so much!!! This has been bugging me for an hour +. And something so simple, I should have figured. I must be tired.

Thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine day of week by passing specific date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270272/how-to-determine-day-of-week-by-passing-specific-date)

Comment: Month is zero based.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 2):

`Month` is Zero based. Try,

```
Date date= (new GregorianCalendar(year, month-1, day)).getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    String dow=f.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Shashank Kadne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21360235/642706) is correct.

## Joda-Time

FYI, this work is simpler and cleaner using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library.

Joda-Time uses sensible one-based counting for things such as:

- **Month-of-Year**
  January = 1, February = 2, and so on.
- **Day-of-Week**
  Monday = 1, Sunday = 7. (Standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) week)

Joda-Time `DateTime` objects know their own time zone, unlike `java.util.Date` objects.

Joda-Time leverages a specified [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) object to render localized strings.

## Example Code

```java
// Specify a time zone rather than rely on default.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );

int year = 2014;
int month = 1; // Sensible one-based counting. January = 1, February = 2, …
int dayOfMonth = 2;

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( year, month, dayOfMonth, 0, 0, 0, timeZone );

// Day-of-week info.
int dayOfWeekNumber = dateTime.getDayOfWeek(); // Standard week (ISO 8601). Monday = 1, Sunday = 7.
DateTime.Property dayOfWeekProperty = dateTime.dayOfWeek();
String dayOfWeekName_Short = dayOfWeekProperty.getAsShortText( Locale.FRANCE );
String dayOfWeekName_Long = dayOfWeekProperty.getAsText( Locale.FRANCE );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dayOfWeekNumber: " + dayOfWeekNumber );
System.out.println( "dayOfWeekName_Short: " + dayOfWeekName_Short );
System.out.println( "dayOfWeekName_Long: " + dayOfWeekName_Long );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2014-01-02T00:00:00.000+01:00
dayOfWeekNumber: 4
dayOfWeekName_Short: jeu.
dayOfWeekName_Long: jeudi
```

## Without Time & Time Zone

If you truly want only date without any time or time zone, then write similar code but with the [LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class.