# Converting 2015-02-24 into a day in Android?

Tags: java, android, date

I'm trying to get the day of the week such as "friday" from a string "2015-02-24" in java but is it possible?

There is a code to convert string, however, I want to get the day string from "2015-02-24". Since, I'm a noob I would be glad to have some tips.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String dateInString = "7-Jun-2013";

try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: please check the java docs before posting here. It helps a lot :)

Comment: Thank you, But it doesn't teach how to get the day from a String format like "2015-02-24". (yyyy/mm/dd)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below-

```
String input_date="2012-08-01";
SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date dt1=format1.parse(input_date);
DateFormat format2=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); 
String finalDay=format2.format(dt1);
```

Reference : [Get day from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270272/how-to-determine-day-of-week-by-passing-specific-date)

Comment: What I want to do is use this String "2015-02-24". yyyy/mm/dd. Not "dd/MM/yyyy" type of order.

Comment: Replace "/" to "-". Reverse the order

Comment: Please, refrain from copy-pasting other [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11758013/1237040) or give them due reference at least.

Answer (score 1):

Try `new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(new Date());`
The "EEEE" should make it display the day of the week.