# Enter date via standard input. Output day of week.

Tags: java, date, calendar, java.util.scanner

I need the code to take a date in the format **mm dd yyyy** (via standard input) and output the week day in plain English.

Sample input (mm dd yyyy): **09 23 2016**

Expected output: **FRIDAY**

Incorrect output: **SUNDAY**

Can anyone please explain what's going wrong here? Thank you.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;

public class DateToDay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
        int day = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
        int year = Integer.parseInt(in.next());

        if ((year > 2000) && (year < 3000)) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

            System.out.println(cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, locale).toUpperCase());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid date entered.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270272/how-to-determine-day-of-week-by-passing-specific-date

Comment: Side note: Consider to use the new Date and Time API introduced in Java SE 8: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 4):

[Calendar.Month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) is Zero based:

> MONTH public static final int MONTH
>
> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a
>   calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian
>   and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the
>   number of months in a year. See Also:

So 9 is october and oct 23 2016 is a sunday. So you have to use `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);`

if you are using java8 you can simply use the new DateTime API:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
System.out.println(date.getDayOfWeek());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
    int day = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
    int year = Integer.parseInt(in.next());

    if ((year > 2000) && (year < 3000)) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        System.out.println(cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, locale).toUpperCase());
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid date entered.");
    }
```

Comment: the minus 1 must be at the value. Not at the key

Comment: Also explain your answer and not post code only

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in here.

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
```

If `Calendar.MONTH` is 0, the month is January.

If `Calendar.MONTH` is 1, the month is February.

If `Calendar.MONTH` is 2, the month is March, and so on.

So, when you enter 09 as an input, the `Calendar.MONTH` becomes October, not September. This is because, as explained above, `Calendar.MONTH` starts from 0.

Try this instead:

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
```