# how to print day of week for two different days at a time using calendar class in java

Tags: java

I want to take year and month from the user one per line and I have to print the day of week for the corresponding year and month with day as 28 for all inputs, i printed the day_of_week for the first input and for second input an exception is thrown by jvm can anyone help me??

For example the inputs are:

- 1999-5
- 2000-7

The console should be able to display the:

- june28th of 1999
- august 28th of 2000.

The month starts from 0 to 11(0-11)

```
import java.util.Calendar;
public class Calendar1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int day = 0;
        String[] input = new String[2];
        int[] year = new int[1];
        int[] month = new int[1];
        String[] split = new String[2];
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Enter The Year And Month(YYYY-M): ");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            input[i] = s.nextLine();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            split = input[i].split("-");
            year[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
            month[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
            cal.set(year[i],month[i],28);
            day[i] = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            System.out.println(day[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably meant  `june28th of 1999   =>  may28th of 1999` have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270272/how-to-determine-day-of-week-by-passing-specific-date

Comment: yes i need to print the days for both inputs at a time i stuck with that

Comment: i got day of week only for first input

Comment: also your `day` is not declared as an array, but used as one. that wouldn't compile even.

Comment: yes but get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) returns an int for only one day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You array bounds seem inappropriate. Probably change your them from

```
int day = 0;
int[] year = new int[1]; // array containing only one element
int[] month = new int[1];
```

to

```
int[] day = new int[N];
int[] year = new int[N];
int[] month = new int[N]; // where N should be the number of lines of your input (2 for the above use case)
```

Comment: @SantoshKumar - good if that solves the problem please be kind enough to accept the answer.

Comment: yes bro :) actually i did a mistake in assigning the array length now i given all arrays length as 2