# How to get 'days' like Monday, Tuesday etc on a given input 'date' in java

Tags: java, date, calendar, dayofweek, days

I'm working on a task where I need to provide specific day like Wednesday, Thursday etc on given input date like 

**Input:**

6 7 2017

**Output:**

Wednesday


Any help would be appreciated thank you.

I have tried using `java.util.Calendar`. I am able to get output like "Sat Sep 05 08:18:27 UTC 2015" but I need only day of week.

Comment: Okay, so you've got a task - have you tried *anything* yet? Do you definitely want English? Are you able to use java.time from Java 8? (I'd strongly advise that instead of java.util.Calendar etc.) We can help you, but we're not just going to write the code for you.

Comment: Maybe this discussion solves it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270272/how-to-determine-day-of-week-by-passing-specific-date

Comment: I used java calendar. From which I can able to get output like "Sat Sep 05 08:18:27 UTC 2015" but I need only 'day'.

Comment: So you've got some code - you should post that in your question. Although I'd strongly recommend *not* using java.util.Calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
      Date dt1=format1.parse(pass your date);
      DateFormat format2=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); 
      String finalDay=format2.format(dt1);
```

Comment: Those troublesome old date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: Thank you, this works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I would follow these steps:

- Parse the string to [a `LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) using [a `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)
- Use [the `LocalDate::getDayOfWeek` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfWeek--) to find the day

Answer (score 1):

Using java8 you will need a local date and the call the method [getDayOfWeek()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfWeek--), which returns an enum with the info you need

example:

```
 LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
 DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = date.getDayOfWeek();
 System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
```