# Calculating Day of The Week JAVA

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a Date class with doomsday rule, in which when the user inputs a year, month and day in a test class, it would output the day of the week.

With the codes below I can find out the dooms day of the year from 1100 to 2900, but then where do I go from here?

(I'm new to Java, so if my code can be cleaner please let me know.

```
private int year;
private int month;
private int day;

public Set <Integer> tue = new HashSet <Integer> (Arrays.asList(20,16,24,28,12));
public Set <Integer> fri = new HashSet <Integer> (Arrays.asList(18,14,22,26));
public Set <Integer> sun = new HashSet <Integer> (Arrays.asList(21,17,13,25,29));
public Set <Integer> wed = new HashSet <Integer> (Arrays.asList(19,15,23,27,11));

public int getDoomsDay() {
   int y = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(this.year).substring(0,2));
   int c;
   if(tue.contains(y)){
       c = 2;
   }
   else if(fri.contains(y)){
       c = 5;
   }
   else if(sun.contains(y)) {
       c = 0;
   }
   else {
       c = 3;
   }
    
   int d = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(this.year).substring(2,4));
   int s = d/12;
   int t = d%12;
   int f = t/s;
   int b;
   if((c+s+t+f) > 6) {
       b = (c+s+t+f)%7;
   }
   else {
       b = (c+s+t+f);
   }
   if(this.year % 4 == 0 && this.year % 100 != 0) {
       return b +1;
   }
   else {
       return b;
   }
    
}
```

Comment: Use `java.time` and take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26265701/12567365).

Comment: @andrewjames This Question is likely a school assignment, so *java.time* would not be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method to compute the day of the week for an arbitrary date.  The formula is based on `March` being the first month of the year, so adjustments need to be made when using our dating system as input.

```
private static String[] weekdays= {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};
public static String dayOfWeek(int m, int d, int y) {
    int c = y / 100;
    y = y % 100;
    m = m - 2;
    if (m <= 0) {
        y = y > 0 ? y-1 : 99;
        c--;
        m += 12;
    }
    // basic formula here.
    int wd =  (d + (int) (.2 * (13 * m - 1)) + y + y / 4 + c / 4
            - 2 * c) % 7;
    return weekdays[wd];
}
```

The explanation and derivation is not hard to understand but it is lengthy and thus omitted here.  It is from **Invitation to Number Theory by Oyestein Ore.**  Fortunately, a PDF version of the book is online at [Invitation to Number Theory](https://www.foresthillshs.org/ourpages/auto/2011/11/2/74617344/Invitation-to-Number-Theory.pdf).  Check out pages 102 - 107.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of improvements you could make. I'll mention a few here:

Firstly, don't use strings to get the century and year-in-century

```
int century = year / 100;
int yearInCentury = year % 100;
```

Secondly, if I understand the algorithm correctly, you don't need to have lists of centuries to convert to anchor day of week. You can calculate the doomsday with:

```
int anchor = (5 * (century % 4)) % 7 + 2;
```

Thirdly,

```
if ((c+s+t+f) > 6) {
    b = (c+s+t+f)%7;
} else {
    b = (c+s+t+f);
}
```

Is actually just the same as

```
b = (c+s+t+f) % 7;
```

There are plenty of other improvements but hopefully that's enough to answer your question.